# excel SQL insert

Tags: sql, excel, import, insert

I am creating an excel spreadsheet that imports a list of Service Desk Analyst Names into Excel from SQL in column A.
Columns B, C, D, etc contain the User IDs for the companies and applications they support.  This data is manually entered by me into excel.

This worked great until we got the first new hire after creating the spreadsheet.  When excel imported the new list of employee names, it did not insert blanks cells where i manually enter their user id's.  This resulted in the user id's being off 1 row for everyone below the new hire.

Example:

BEFORE (good!)

```
Adam userid1 userid2 userid3

 Beth userid4 userid5 userid6

 David userid7 userid8 userid9

 Eddie userid10 userid11 userid12
```

AFTER (Cathy is the new hire) - David's UID's are now in Cathy's row.

```
Adam userid1 userid2 userid3

 Beth userid4 userid5 userid6

 Cathy userid7 userid8 userid9

 David userid10 userid11 userid12

 Eddie
```

DESIRED RESULTS:

```
 Adam userid1 userid2 userid3

 Beth userid4 userid5 userid6

 Cathy

 David userid7 userid8 userid9

 Eddie userid10 userid11 userid12
```

I am hoping the resolution lies in the SQL command, the command am using is:

```
Select NAME From "DATABASENAME" order by NAME
```

please note, i am not an admin on my PC so addons are not possible.
i realize the BEST solution is to have the ID's as part of the SQL database, but i have to make do with what i have.
although i think have have some measurable skills with EXCEL, i am almost completely new to any kind of SQL coding.

i really need this to work as an HR list of names is the best way i know of to insure accuracy in my job.  My appreciation in advance to all those willing to help!

Comment: How do you add a new employee ? How do you import in your excel ? What are those userid and how are they used/modified/imported ?

Comment: new employee names are imported from the SQL server.
whereas the names are imported from SQL and cause the list of employees to grow, the user id's are manually entered and therefore "static" in their location in excel.
this is the crux of the problem that i am trying to figure out.